# Clearing all seaborn plots each time running the code in plots tab spyder IDE

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn, spyder

I create some plots in one run of code, the plots are in plots tab. I tried to delete it all each time i rerun it but somehow the previous plots are still there not closing, it only creates new plots without clearing the previous plots from the previous run. I already tried to use `plt.close('all')` but it does not work. How do i clear all plots every time i rerun the code?

Here's my code

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.close('all')
avo_sales = pd.read_csv('avocados.csv')
avo_sales.rename(columns = {'4046':'small Hass sold','4225':'large Hass sold','4770':'xlarge Hass sold'},
                 inplace= True)

for column in avo_sales.columns[2:11]:
    sns.set()
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    sns.set(style="ticks")
    sns.boxplot(column, data= avo_sales)  # column is chosen here
    sns.despine(offset=10, trim=True)
```

Comment: Not removing plots created by previous runs is a confusing situation. It seems Spyder developpers are using the same paradigm than for the console: Keep the history until the kernel is restarted (which in practice means never), however while runs outputs in the console are separated by the run command, plots are not distinguishable. To me this is a questionable choice, at least there should be an option to clear outputs, console and plots, automatically prior to running the code again.

Answer (score 4):

The images in the plots pane are handled by Spyder and are [not reachable from the IPython console](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/11607#issuecomment-589277748).

A simple solution would be to press the "remove images" icon before you re-run the code:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to even get Spyder to put plots in the plot pane, but here's a few things that might work.

1. Try disabling some of the pane options:

[image]

2. Try some magic functions:

**%reset** - reset everything

**%matplotlib** - puts all plots inline with your code in the interactive window

**%clear** - clears the interactive window

3. Use IPython directly to help (via: https://gist.github.com/stsievert/8655158355b7155b2dd8):

```
from IPython import get_ipython

get_ipython().magic('reset -sf')
```

Comment: in the point 2, where do i put that functions? if its in the python console, then i need to type it each time i wanna rerun my code?

Comment: I am not sure, haha. Maybe you could try it in your loop?  I use %clear by itself in the interpreter to clean everything up, but haven't integrated it into a script.  Here's a link to the list of all the magic commands if the ones I suggested don't work: `https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html`